# Facebook login and like

Tags: php, facebook

My application has an integrated facebook login and contain articles which user can like. User should be able to like an article only if he is directly logged into the website. If not logged in, I am using a transparent layer over the like button which on click opens the popup and user is allowed to login to their FB account.

### Right now I am facing the below issue:

After user logs in from the popup and returned to application, the article is not yet 'liked' as he hasnt clicked on the like but clicked on the overlay on the like button. And the user has to click the 'like' again. In this way certain articles are losing significant likes as user after logging in from popup thinks he already liked the article.

Can anyone suggest me something in overcoming this "issue". I am using PHP.

If my explanation is not sufficient, let me know, I will try to be more specific.

Thanks.

### Code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['User']) && empty($_SESSION['User'])){
//show login button
}  else{
//show logged in user credentials
}
```

creating overlay in the following way

```
<div class="FB_Like">
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="URL" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: some of the code you've tried would help

Comment: ok will update in a moment

Comment: Never used fb api before, but the only way that user had to log in is because he clicked the 'like' button, isn't it?

Comment: I added code. User has to click on login from my website header which opens a popup and then he is allowed to login.

Comment: @luchosrock No, you can have separate actions, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/#facebook_object

Answer (score 2):

There are two logical ways to work around your issue, both consist of design:

- simply do not use the overlay system you now use, instead disable the like button and display "Login to like" message, so users first have to login, then like, but they are made aware of this by the message. Not very user friendly, though.
- another solution, is if clicking the like button and they are not logged in, after succesfully logging in send the like action to facebook, or simply trigger the click event of the like button - both solutions would be clientside events. "However there is no way to do this that won't get you penalized by Facebook if they find out." to quote another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365205/how-can-i-trigger-facebooks-like-action-without-using-facebook-like-button).

Comment: Ya i came across several articles where I/ any website is not allowed to click on the like through any script and it should be done only through direct human interaction. Anyway, I found the second one more sensible in my case. But imagine a user is already logged in facebook in another tab and that user clicked like on my article, How can I send this click on 'like' interaction to my website header to log him in my website ?

Comment: Don't know how your website is actually designed, so I'm going to make some assumptions. When you login the facebook response is to send you the user id of the logged in user, which should be stored on you server's user session. However many tabs a user has open, server side he has only one session open, with the user id and you can `$this->getFacebook()->api("/".$id."/likes", 'post');` serverside. *Note: Assumes your site handles user's session.